# RestKit identificationAttributes not working for collectionIndex

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

My use case is that for a specific collection endpoint, I am creating a local Core-Data backed junction table to specify order. This is an abstract object; not one that I can directly map.

I am successfully creating a representation of the collection, all objects, and all orders. On subsequent requests, duplicate order objects are created.

My identificationAttributes array contains an attribute representing the page offset, and an attribute representing the relative order for the request. (query parameters are based on offset & limit. Order of an item = offset + relative order).

It looks to me like this is an issue with RestKit (duplicates are not created if i remove the collectionIndex attribute, additionally I have verified that the correct numerical value is set to this attribute); but I'm new to it. Can collectionIndex be used as an identification attribute, or is this disallowed?

Comment: Note: I also tried the artificial identifier attributes as per this issue: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1604 but it's not working as of 0.24.1; What happens is I end up with only one order-object, and I get duplicates every new request. Possibly this is because willSave is not called during the creation of the individual objects?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the RKMapperOperation, and found this code, which shows that the collectionIndex is calculated only after identification attributes are processed. Without a change to RestKit, this is not possible. The method objectForRepresentation:withMapping: retrieves the existing object, and its index is then changed.

```
   [objectsToMap enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id mappableObject, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        id destinationObject = [self objectForRepresentation:mappableObject withMapping:mapping];
        if (destinationObject) {
            mappingData.collectionIndex = index;
            BOOL success = [self mapRepresentation:mappableObject toObject:destinationObject isNew:YES atKeyPath:keyPath usingMapping:mapping metadataList:metadataList];
            if (success) [mappedObjects addObject:destinationObject];
        }
        *stop = [self isCancelled];
    }];
```